# Where are the saved import mapping configs stored?

Tags: import

I have been working on a local CiviCRM install to test importing contacts from a CSV file to the Civi contacts. I am ready to move this import process to our hosted test site but would not like to have to recreate the import mapping again. Are the saved mapping saved in a particular DB table or config file? I cannot find any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 3):

They looked to be stored in two tables.

civicrm_mapping
civicrm_mapping_fields

The tables are pretty standard.  The first has the header info and id, e.g what you called the mapping and the second has what each field is mapped to.  The foreign key is civicrm_mapping.id = civicrm_mapping_fields.mapping_id

I'm pretty sure if you haven't saved any mappings in the target system or don't care about any you have, you can import the two tables into the target system and be good to go.  Of course, you mileage may vary and do test, but it looks like the target system is a test system.